# ActiveMQ: how to programmatically monitor embedded broker

Tags: activemq-classic

I want to monitor an embedded ActiveMQ 5.8 broker from inside the code.

- How can this be done?
- Do I need a JMX connection? I want to prevent exposing JMX
- Is there a way of accessing [`org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx`](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.8.0/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/jmx/package-summary.html) Beans without JMX?
- Are there Hooks, Listeners, Events, ... that can be attached to the broker itself?
- If this is a really bad idea, why?

Comment: Did you managed with Tim Bish answer?
I'm trying to make the same monitoring and I'm not finding how to programatically know if ActiveMQ is working fine or not

Comment: @JoãoRebelo As far as I can remember, I used Tim's answer to implement my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access all the standard JMX MBeans from within the process that has an embedded broker without creating the JMX connector that would expose them to the outside world.  First you need to tell the embedded broker to enable JMX but not create the connector.

```
    brokerService = new BrokerService();
    brokerService.setPersistent(false);
    brokerService.setAdvisorySupport(false);
    brokerService.setSchedulerSupport(true);
    brokerService.setPopulateJMSXUserID(true);
    brokerService.setSchedulerSupport(true);
    brokerService.getManagementContext().setCreateConnector(false);
```

Then in your code you can access the JMS MBeans as normal for instance to get the BrokerViewMBean:

```
protected BrokerViewMBean getProxyToBroker() throws MalformedObjectNameException, JMSException {
    ObjectName brokerViewMBean = new ObjectName(
        "org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost");
    BrokerViewMBean proxy = (BrokerViewMBean) brokerService.getManagementContext()
            .newProxyInstance(brokerViewMBean, BrokerViewMBean.class, true);
    return proxy;
}
```

Or to get a QueueViewMBean:

```
protected QueueViewMBean getProxyToQueue(String name) throws MalformedObjectNameException, JMSException {
    ObjectName queueViewMBeanName = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,destinationType=Queue,destinationName="+name);
    QueueViewMBean proxy = (QueueViewMBean) brokerService.getManagementContext()
            .newProxyInstance(queueViewMBeanName, QueueViewMBean.class, true);
    return proxy;
}
```

And similarly a TopicViewMBean.

```
protected TopicViewMBean getProxyToTopic(String name) throws MalformedObjectNameException, JMSException {
    ObjectName topicViewMBeanName = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,destinationType=Topic,destinationName="+name);
    TopicViewMBean proxy = (TopicViewMBean) brokerService.getManagementContext()
            .newProxyInstance(topicViewMBeanName, TopicViewMBean.class, true);
    return proxy;
}
```