# Monitor Embedded ActiveMQ

Tags: java, jvm, activemq-classic

I am using a embedded ActiveMQ in my application, the queue works excellent,

Now we want a way to be able to monitor this ActiveMQ, due to its embedded nature we cannot use the default web console provided by ActiveMQ.

I have had a look here http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-monitor-activemq.html , the provided options haven't helped much in my cause due to following reasons

- Using `JConsole` is not a nice option because it uses up much of server resources and causes JVM to be slow.
- `StatisticsPlugin` is a nice approach **but** doesn't provide a UI view, and gets reset on every server restart (This is what we will use if nothing else is found).

Have also had a look at similar question on SO [ActiveMQ: how to programmatically monitor embedded broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183907/activemq-how-to-programmatically-monitor-embedded-broker) , this is not what I want

Recently have heard about a tool called [Hawtio](http://hawt.io/) , but this also seems to be useful when ActiveMq is running as standalone instance, (Please Correct If I am wrong on this, Any pointers will be definitely helpful)

So the help that I need is

- Is Hawtio really useful for embedded instance ?
- Are there any other tools availablle to achieve this goal?

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Check out the Integrated Console-- https://mediadriver.com/software/ it connects via JMX and supports all deployment modes.  Disclaimer: I am co-founder of Media Driver.

Comment: Vihar, if you found a way to monitor embedded ActiveMQ, could you share please?

Answer (score 0):

I have used hawtio, its very useful tools for monitoring ActiveMQ. It used JMX internally which takes you java process running and monitor it.

Comment: This post is about embedded brokers, not standalone